# Copy Application(.exe) in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I started using C++ for now, and I have a problem. **I never used C++ before** but I have used C#.

I want to copy my app, but I can't because if I get the app path with `char* path = __argv[0];` and copy the file using `CopyFile(path, anotherpath, TRUE);` I get a compiler error:

> argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCTSTR"

If I try converting with this code:

```
char* path = __argv[0];
wchar_t wtext[20];
mbstowcs(wtext, path, strlen(path) + 1);
LPWSTR ptr = wtext;
```

It doesn't work either.

And if I try to print this:

```
cout << wtext;
```

it shows "random numbers and letters"

[image]

I don't know how to copy a file from a `char*`, sorry but I'm noob in C++.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: the last parameter to `mbstowcs` should be `20` to match the length of `wtext`, you should also check the return value of `mbstowcs` to make sure it succeeded

Comment: The simple answer is to use `CopyFileA` instead of `CopyFile` As long as you don't have non-ASCII characters in your filenames that should work fine.

Comment: This question is windows specific.   No such thing as `__argv` in standard C++ - in fact, it is a reserved identifier, so using a name with two leading underscores gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: The question that you should be asking is how to get the full path to your executable file as UTF-16 text. I suggest that you ask that question instead of this one.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is trivial:

- Enable Unicode support by defining the `_UNICODE` and `UNICODE` preprocessor symbols (you are already doing this, judging by the error diagnostic).
- Provide a Unicode entry point named `wmain` (rather than `main`).
- Either access the command line arguments from `wmain`, or use [__wargv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv) in place of `__argv`.

---

Note: Passing the name of the executable as the first command line argument is a *convention*, not a contract. If you want a robust solution, query for the executable's name instead, using e.g. [GetModuleFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamew) or the Microsoft-specific [_get_wpgmptr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/get-wpgmptr) CRT extension.